# argument to a formal proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, logic-translation

Convert the following argument to a formal proof.

> If the software contains a serious bug ($B$), or the hardware
> is faulty ($H$) then the code will generate an error
> ($E$). The tests passed ($T$). An error would cause the tests
> to fail. Therefore the software does not contain a serious
> bug.

*Solution*:

$\lnot(B \lor H) \to T$

Is it correct?

Comment: Not clear: the argument is made of *premises* : 1) "If the software contains a serious bug (B), or the hardware is faulty (H) then the code will generate an error (E)", formalizable as $(B \lor H) \to E$; 2) "The tests passed", i.e. $T$; 3) "An error would cause the tests to fail", i.e. $E \to \lnot T$; and 4) a *conclusion* : $\lnot B$.

Comment: When you talk about "formal proof", which formal system do you use? In other words, which inference rules are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct. The argument has $3$ premises ($(B \lor H) \to E$, $T$, 
$E \to \lnot T$) and one conclusion ($\lnot B$):

$(B \lor H) \to E$

$T$

$E \to \lnot T$

==========

$\lnot B$

The exercise asks to prove that the argument above is valid, i.e. that if you assume the $3$ premises then the conclusion holds by necessity. A formal proof should show, by means of elementary logic steps, how the conclusion follows from the premises. Concretely, the formal proof depends on the inference rules that you are allowed to use.